# Buffer to openGL rendering android?

Tags: android, image, opengl-es, rendering

In my Application, I am using Android Camera API to access Camera of device. I'm receiving camera frames as byte array on callback `onPreviewFrame()`. I have to process the image/bye array and give to OpenGL display.

I'm not configuring camera to `setPreviewDisplay(holder)` or `setPreviewTexture(surface)` for the frames to be rendered on view directly.

I have been googling.. still no useful reference found.

Please suggest useful information or source for image buffer rendering on OPENGL?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is how to render a `texture`, which in this case is your image byte array data. You will want to create a `vertex buffer` object with attributes - position and `texture` coordinates. Basically you will be creating a quad and mapping the corners of the texture to it. You can find a good example [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/)